# Is there a possibility of using Custom Properties to set binding value in SoapUI

Tags: binding, wsdl, soapui

I am running some test with SoapUI, there is a fail due to not find the Custom Properties of the project in the binding value. I get a `NullPointerException` when I run the tests with command-line, though the test run successfully. In the SoapUI I cannot define the binding value while I can do it with other properties as the Definition URL.
Does anyone know a possiblity of using project properties in the binding value?

**EDIT**

I need to define a variable binding value depending on Custom Properties because I need to run the test in different environments. I would like to be able to do the same i do with the Definition URL, something like

`${#Project#hostnameAndPort}/${#Project#serviceBatchPath}/wsdlname`

[image: Soapui]

Comment: You mean to say that `Binding` value to be changed? I believe that it comes from wsdl, I am afraid that can be changed. By the way, what is your use case?

Comment: thanks, I edited the question

Comment: I believe that you want to change the `endpoint` or `Definition URL` and point to different server in another environment. But not the `Binding` value. Is that right? Like it is mentioned earlier, `Binding` value can't be change. Because, service is associated with that `namespace` which can neither be modified nor it works.

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/properties/working-with-properties.html#4-Example----Centralized-Endpoint ?